# Huge request block time on XHR request made on Firefox

Tags: javascript, spring, google-chrome, firefox, xmlhttprequest

There is some very strange behavior of the same request on Chrome and Firefox.
I have one button that triggers POST request to a Spring-boot backend, it's kind of long-running, takes ~5-6min.
On Chrome, there are no issues and every time I get the expected response for the above-mentioned time(5-6min), and only 1 request is received by the backend.
On Firefox on the other hand I make the same POST request through that button and the strange thing is that the request stays blocked for 6mins and after that is somehow retriggered. This happens 9 out of 10 times.
This results in 2 requests made to the backend from a single request in the frontend.. at least this is what it looks like from the logs that I put in the backend.
The second request starts exactly after the block time.

There aren`t any other XHR requests being executed at the same time.

Below is a screenshot of how it looks:

[image: Block time on firefox]

Does anyone have any idea what might cause this behaviour on Firefox?

Comment: How the xhr request initiated? Is it as synchronous request or asynchronous request? Sometimes it is possible when multiple event handlers are registered to that button.

Comment: @Wazeed it's asynchronous, and no other handle is registered to that button.

Comment: Could you provide your request and some code please.

Comment: @IvanPonomarev I'm not sure if I'm allowed to copy/paste company code here. Basically there is not much special with the code itself. Its making jQuery.ajax() call setting the type of request (POST) , json body, headers and having a beforeSend function.

Comment: @КалоянНиков, please check this once in firefox browser. Right click on action button, then Inspect Element, in element panel you could see an `ev` bubble beside to button code, click on it and check how many handlers does that hows?

Comment: @Wazeed its only one. And wonder why that works in Chrome everytime. On Firefox sometimes it doesnt have block time but 9/10 it fails

Comment: i wonder could it be blocked by this TLS setup i think its not normal to take 6 mins for that

Comment: try to simulate requests from curl and cli, are those working as intended? if yes, checkout and compare headers that are by default are sent from chrome and from firefox? Is the CORS not violated?

Comment: @IvanPonomarev thanks for the hints. I tried what you suggested to print the headers and i found out that these three headers are provided on Chrome but missing in Firefox
Header 'sec-fetch-site' = same-origin
Header 'sec-fetch-mode' = cors|
Header 'sec-fetch-dest' = empty

Could this be the reason for the blockage?